# /socket.io/socket.io.js not responding the js script content

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, socket.io

domain.com/socket.io/socket.io.js return default not found response in newly configured server. but this same code working fine in old servers.

Based on the troubleshooting, I understand that the main reason of socket connection attempt fail due to domain.com/socket.io/socket.io.js not providing the script file. Anyone have idea about this ?

Comment: Can you add the details like which script file is missing. What is that script file used for, any other difference between new and old servers?

Comment: https://test-domain.com/socket.io/socket.io.js will send back a js file.